# What is the best way to retrieve a TextFormField's value when using an initialValue and a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Dart/Flutter code currently has a form which is supposed to edit a previously entered appointment. It uses initialValue to set the initial value of the form's fields to the old values, and it is inside a FutureBuilder because i need to retrieve the event's from Google Calendar API to fill the initialValue fields. However i'm not sure how to retrieve whatever the user enters in the fields. To my understanding, controllers cannot be used when an initialValue is used, and onChanged requires a setState to work which would keep refreshing my FutureBuilder. Is there a more appropriate way to do it?

I've tried both controllers and onChanged and i'm not sure how to best go about this.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a minimal code example of what you've tried